# Javascript onClick Doesnt work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Good evening.

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function action1() {
    var x = document.getElementById('MarcaGravadaPedra');
    x.style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('EstruturaSagrada').style = "display: none;"
    document.getElementById('objectosagrado').style = "display: none;"
    HideAll();
}
</script>
```

And on the html itself, have a form, and some buttons inside it:

```
<input type="button" id="ObjectoSagradoButton" value="Objecto Sagrado" onClick="action1();"/>
```

Though, this code works on firefox, but not on IE or Chrome. I've tryed everything, but cant seem to make this work.

That Button will make some divs appear, and others disappear.

```
<div id="MarcaGravadaPedra">Testing1</div>
```

Comment: any errors on the console log?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w9jSj/ works in chrome like it does in firefox

Comment: Where is the rest of your HTML?

I just want to see if you have DOM elements with ID `EstruturaSagrada` and `objectosagrado`.

Comment: I've changed all the javascript to JQuery. Found it easyer and works in every browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine your code to work in any browser. You've a couple of these odd lines overriding the `style` object with a string:

```
document.getElementById(...).style = "display: none;"
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById(...).style.display = "none";
```

or:

```
document.getElementById(...).setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick.

Use onclick instead of onClick.

Detailed

Press F12 on Chrome. The developers tools will appear. It's something really useful for web developers.

Now, go to the menu and you will find a lens. Click it and then click the button. Right click on highlighted text and select edit as HTML. change the onClick per onclick and try again.

I'm not a native english speaker, sorry for the mistakes.

Hope it will be useful and have a nice coding night.

Comment: HTML is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be subject to the content Security policy. if that's so, the code isn't supposed to work. besides, using inline onclick is a bad idea. try this code instead :

```
function action1() {
var x = document.getElementById('MarcaGravadaPedra');
x.style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById('EstruturaSagrada').style = "display: none;"
document.getElementById('objectosagrado').style = "display: none;"
HideAll();
}

document.getElementById('ObjectoSagradoButton').addEventListener('click',action1);
```

more information about content security policy can be found here at 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Introducing_Content_Security_Policy)

Comment: I had tryed this one, but also seemt to not work. Though changed all with JQuery.